# Add Top 1 and Order By to select statement with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a VIEW in sql server and joined several tables with inner joins.

Problems.

1. When I added "order by nameRela.WNAME_INDIVIDUAL_LAST" in the inner join statement, the next inner join is highlighted in red, saying 'incorrect syntax near inner'
2. When I added "top 1" inside the select statement, it also give me errors in red.

With a select statement with multipled inner joins, what is the correct syntax to add 'Top 1' or select the first record and add the order by

Thanks

```
select  top 500    
    rtrim(pendk_policy) as Id
    ,case (pendk_company) when '17' then 'BNR' when 'WP' then 'PENN' end as Company
    ,case rtrim(pendk_policy) when '' then '--' else rtrim(pendk_policy) end  as PolicyNumber 
    ,'InForce' as [Type]
    , (
        case
            when WPOLC_CONTRACT_CODE = 'A' then 'Active'
            when WPOLC_CONTRACT_CODE = 'T' then 'Terminated'     
            when WPOLC_CONTRACT_CODE = 'P' then 'Pending'  
            when WPOLC_CONTRACT_CODE = 'S' then 'Suspended'  
            when WPOLC_CONTRACT_CODE = 'H' then 'On Hold'
        end
    ) as [Status]
    ,  top 1  rtrim(nameRela.wname_individual_first) + ' '+ rtrim(nameRela.wname_individual_middle) + ' ' + rtrim(nameRela.wname_individual_last) as Customer
from  
    WPOLC_TABL wpolc
    inner join WRELA_TABL wrela on (wrela.WRELA_COMPANY_CODE = wpolc.WPOLC_COMPANY_CODE and wrela.WRELA_POLICY_NUMBER = wpolc.WPOLC_POLICY_NUMBER and wrela.WRELA_RELATE_CODE = 'sa')

    inner join WRELA_TABL custRela on (custRela.WRELA_COMPANY_CODE = wpolc.WPOLC_COMPANY_CODE and custRela.WRELA_POLICY_NUMBER = wpolc.WPOLC_POLICY_NUMBER 
        and custRela.WRELA_RELATE_CODE in ('in', 'ji' , 'je')) order by  custRela.WRELA_RELATE_CODE

    inner join wname_tabl nameRela on (custRela.WRELA_COMPANY_CODE = nameRela.WNAME_COMPANY_CODE and custRela.WRELA_NAME_ID = nameRela.WNAME_NAME_ID )
    order by nameRela.WNAME_INDIVIDUAL_LAST

    inner join PENDKEY_TABL pk on (wrela.WRELA_COMPANY_CODE = pk.PendK_company and wrela.WRELA_POLICY_NUMBER = pk.PENDK_POLICY)
```

Comment: Huh?  Neither of those are valid SQL syntax.  What could you possibly be trying to do?

Comment: Please post some sample data and your desired results.  We can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish with this query.  As it stands, you can't use multiple `TOP X` statements to apply to different columns and you can't use `ORDER BY` after the `JOIN` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The order by should come last in the query. The basic format is:

```
Select 
From
  inner join
where
order by
```